# Search for a key in hashtable and average associated values Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I have a script where I'm trying to get the test name and store it into a hashtable as the key, then get a high test score and a low test score and store those 2 as the values. Then, I would like to take and allow the user to search for a test name and see the high and low scores. what I have currently is:

```
$testInfo = @{}
$testName = read-host "Please enter the name of the test"
$testHigh = read-host "Please enter the high score of the test"
$testLow = read-host "Please enter the low score of the test"
$testInfo.Add($testName, $testHigh + " " + $testLow
$search = read-host "Please enter the name of the test you'd like to view the average score of"
```

This code successfully stores the high and low scores to that test name, but I need a way to find the name of the test with the $search value. Then average the two test scores stored in the values part.

Answer (score 17):

It depends on how you want to use it, but there are several ways:

```powershell
$testInfo.ContainsKey($search)
```

That will return a `$true`/`$false` if the key exists.

You can also iterate through the keys:

```powershell
foreach($key in $testInfo.Keys.GetEnumerator()) {
    $key
}
```

You could just reference it:

```powershell
$testInfo[$search]
# or
$testInfo.$search
```

You can choose the way to reference/use it that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, it will be easier to accomplish this with with a nested hash table specifically, or a custom object.  For a nested hash table, you need to add the test scores as an additional hash table for the value of the test name.  Afterwards, you would loop thru all keys for a matching key search and then create an average.

Since the test score values are saved as a string, it is important to define the $avg variable as an integer.

```
$testInfo = @{}
$testName = read-host "Please enter the name of the test"
$testHigh = read-host "Please enter the high score of the test"
$testLow = read-host "Please enter the low score of the test"
$nest = @{High=$testHigh; Low=$testLow}
$testInfo.Add($testName, $nest)
$search = read-host "Please enter the name of the test you'd like to view the average score of"
$avg = 0
$count = 0
$testInfo[$search].GetEnumerator() | % { $avg += $_.value; $count++ }
Write-Host "The average score for test $search is $($avg/$count)."
```

I included a count, but that can be dropped if you only ever to intend to enter 2 values of course.